# :after content displaying over original element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

The `.back-btn` servers as a background image of an arrow. I am wanting the `:after` content to display under the image. I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I have tried adding `margin-top` and `position:relative` to the `:after` element, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```css
.back-btn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 2%;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/41-200.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
}
.back-btn:after {
    content: "Back";
    color: #303030;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="back-btn"></div>
```

Comment: You can't put anything **under** a background image...

Comment: Gotcha. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "under" vertically? Or under in terms of z-index stacking?

Comment: I meant vertically. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving `.back-btn` a height, change that height to padding top:

```css
.back-btn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 2%;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/41-200.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    text-align:center; /* optional if you want to centre your text */
}
.back-btn:after {
    content: "Back";
    color: #303030;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="back-btn"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
.back-btn:after {
    content: "Back";
    color: #303030;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

[update link of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/9m8hfgux/)